# Why is it that when "This site is currently in read-only mode", others are still able to participate?

Tags: discussion, support, read-only-mode

I have gotten this message `"This site is currently in read-only mode"` for the last six hours. Why is it that I am getting the site in *"read only"*, but there are still questions being asked, answers being posted, and other *"non-read only"* activity going on?

Also I have seen this message before, and understand the time-outs for maintenance, but it has never been for *this* long. Just wondering if this has anything to with my account in particular or if there is some other reason for this.

Comment: The outage ended hours ago.  Refresh your browser?  BTW, the outage also included *this site,* the one you just posted your question to.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yea I just had to close and reopen my browser. It didn't work with a refresh. Any guess why? Also, should I delete this post?

Comment: I had this issue earlier today, the site was in readonly, but after refreshing cache it showed new questions that had been asked within that minute, but was still in readonly mode. was very strange. Waiting a few more minutes resolved the issue.

Comment: I experienced this as well last night, but it resolved after a few minutes, like it did for Kevin

Comment: [Dupe on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231131/why-did-i-see-new-questions-posted-on-a-site-in-read-only-mode), with a likely explanation by [Steven](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231138/163863) (cc @Kevin)